# Flutter in_app_purchase, show content after purchase

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

I take code from offical in_app_purchases documentation, purchases work correctly.

I have function that show paid content, and i need to run it after purchase done correctly, but i don't know where i need to put it, because i steel don't inderstand purchases 100% correctly.

this is my code

```
 final InAppPurchase _inAppPurchase = InAppPurchase.instance;
  final String _productID = '1d7ea644f690ffa';

  bool _available = true;
  List<ProductDetails> _products = [];
  List<PurchaseDetails> _purchases = [];
  StreamSubscription<List<PurchaseDetails>>? _subscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    final Stream<List<PurchaseDetails>> purchaseUpdated = _inAppPurchase.purchaseStream;
    _subscription = purchaseUpdated.listen((purchaseDetailsList) {
      setState(() {
        _purchases.addAll(purchaseDetailsList);
        _listenToPurchaseUpdated(purchaseDetailsList);
      });
    }, onDone: () {
      _subscription!.cancel();
    }, onError: (error) {
      _subscription!.cancel();
    });

    _initialize();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _subscription!.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _initialize() async {
    _available = await _inAppPurchase.isAvailable();

    List<ProductDetails> products = await _getProducts(
      productIds: Set<String>.from(
        [_productID],
      ),
    );

    setState(() {
      _products = products;
    });
  }

  void _listenToPurchaseUpdated(List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) {
    purchaseDetailsList.forEach((PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async {
      switch (purchaseDetails.status) {
        case PurchaseStatus.pending:
          //  _showPendingUI();
          break;
        case PurchaseStatus.purchased:
          break;
        case PurchaseStatus.restored:
          // bool valid = await _verifyPurchase(purchaseDetails);
          // if (!valid) {
          //   _handleInvalidPurchase(purchaseDetails);
          // }
          break;
        case PurchaseStatus.error:
          print(purchaseDetails.error!);
          // _handleError(purchaseDetails.error!);
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }

      if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase) {
        await _inAppPurchase.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
        CheckListModel.addPaidData(purchaseDetails.productID);
      }
    });
  }

  Future<List<ProductDetails>> _getProducts({required Set<String> productIds}) async {
    ProductDetailsResponse response = await _inAppPurchase.queryProductDetails(productIds);

    return response.productDetails;
  }

  void _subscribe({required ProductDetails product}) {
    final PurchaseParam purchaseParam = PurchaseParam(productDetails: product);
    _inAppPurchase.buyNonConsumable(
      purchaseParam: purchaseParam,
    );
  }
```

_subscribe function start when user click on special button in ui

function that show paid contenct name is

CheckListModel.addPaidData(purchaseDetails.productID);

when function start it create file paid.paid in getApplicationDocumentsDirectory, if it doesn't exist, and add in it productID . That what must happen

Where i need to place this function?

Comment: You need to have one flag in local storage in which you store the status of payment and check that flag on every screen and if payment is done then only you can enable certain features. For storing variable you can use SharedPreferences.

Comment: Having a flag in the local storage is a bad idea particularly for this functionality because what if paid user clean the data/cache of app? The paid functionality would also be gone @KaranMehta

Comment: The better approach would be to Store the expiration date in online database like It could be Firebase and whenever user would try to access the paid content, you can then run the code to check if the today date is greater than expiration date and bingo!